# How to maintain variables in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I have few records say

```
session1    click1    time1 

session1    click2    time2

session1    click3    time3

session2    click1    time1

session2    click2    time2

session2    click3    time3
```

now I need to calculate visit time for each click in session

```
session1    click1    time1    (time2-time1)

session1    click2    time2    (time3-time2)

session1    click3    time3     0

session2    click1    time1    (time2-time1)

session2    click2    time2    (time3-time2)

session2    click3    time3    0
```

Which component of hadoop can I use to get the above functionality?

Comment: You question is a bit too broad to be precisely answered. The Hadoop component you are interested in is probably MapReduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use Map Reduce.

Map could emit Key,Value as `SessionID, Click-Time` pair. On the reducer end, sort the `Click-Time` pair by order of time. So you could easily get the first, second and third time of clicks. Rest is simple, just emit `Key, Click, Time, Time Difference` (each separated by delimiter tab) for each pair from the reducer. The value of the reducer could be `NullWritable`.